# Firmar el setup de mi app

Tags: firma-digital

Bueno la verdad que no sé mucho de firmar apps ni certificados pero por lo que tengo entendido hay que gastarse una pasta para comprar uno y paso. ¿Se puede firmar un ejecutable (en este caso un setup) con el Certificado Digital? O es un certificado que no sirve para software. He buscado pero no encuentro nada relacionado con esto en ningún sitio. Si se puede, para firmar usaría SignTool de Microsoft.